# "Mysql has gone away" when fired in cli mode from rabbitmq worker

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I've two instances of my Wordpress project running on a box (separate code base & db). Both of which performs background tasks when triggered by rabbitmq and update data on their respective db.

For this I've created two exchanges in rabbitmq (E-1 and E-2). This way I ensure that messages are always delivered to their respective worker.
i.e. A message triggered from Instance-1 will go to E-1 and be delivered to Worker-1 cause all of this is tied together by E-1 and so on.

The problem is : My worker-1 which runs on E-1 works fine but the exact replica of that worker (Worker-2) which runs on E-2 results in "Mysql has gone away error" for any query it tries to fire.

I've checked DB configuration and permissions, all is good.

Any suggestions, what might be causing this. Do I need to look into running two exchanges on rabbitmq?

Looking forward to suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: There can be many reasons for this error, check following [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) for the one applies in your case

Comment: Thanks @DharmeshPatel, but ofcourse I've gone through the entire list before. my concern is the same piece of code when fired from Exchange-1 is working, but from Exchange-2 it isn't. I'm guessing it has something to do with the rabbitmq exchanges are setup. Feedback appreciated.

Comment: That might help to find out what's going on with your mysql http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/sqlstatehy000-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away-2013-01-02/

Comment: rabbitmq might try to leave the connection opened for too long for instance…

Comment: @user1717735, you're correct. I moved all my workers DB interactions to a custom class, which forcefully closes the connection and that solved the issue.
Moreover wordpress's DBAL (wpdb object) doesn't even come close handling db transactions initiated in cli mode (I guess),So having a custom class is the only choice I had.

Comment: Tweaking wordpress isn't always a piece of cake! Fortunately you found out